# When is $\int_{[0, \infty)}f.d\lambda_1 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0, n]} f.d\lambda_1$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In my Probability course there are some lebesgue Integrals wrt. Lebesgue Measure. In the notes there is a theorem that says:

> Let $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then it is Lebesgue
> integrable and the integrals are the same:
> $$\int_{[a, b]}f.d\lambda_1 = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$$

Sometimes we have to evaluate integrals over unbounded intervals, like $[0,\infty)$. My lecturer would rewrite the integral as $$\int_{[0, \infty)}f.d\lambda_1 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0, n]} f.d\lambda_1$$
so that we can use the theorem above. My question is when is this valid? Do we not have to worry about whether the sequence of integrals converge or does it always converge in this form?

Comment: You may want to check out integral convergence theorems, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: These are what make the Lebesgue integral more powerful than the Riemann integral.

Answer (score 2):

In the sense of improper Riemann integration, the RHS is basically the definition of the LHS (not exactly, because in improper Riemann integration you send the limit to infinity continuously, but this distinction usually doesn't matter).

In the sense of Lebesgue integration, you can view the RHS as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,\infty)} f 1_{[0,n]} \, d \lambda_1$ and then apply one of the Lebesgue integral convergence theorems. In this case you can say that $f 1_{[0,n]}$ is dominated by $f$, so by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, the RHS converges to the LHS if the LHS converges absolutely, or in other words if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$. If it isn't, then the question doesn't really make sense because the LHS is simply undefined, whether the RHS is defined or not.